# Swift: how to access each section's cellectionView in Compositional Layouts

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, collectionview

I've finally started to use Compositional Layouts of CollectionView, which is the newest way to layout collectionView.

I grabbed how to layout it in iOS 13 but I'm not sure how to access each section's CollectionView.

I'd like to use `func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_:)` for the first section's collectionView that is one of the added sections.  However, `UICollectionViewDelegate` is applied to the main collectionView (which means there's no way to apply delegate methods to each section?).

In the view hierarchy, the target that I'd like to access is in `_UICollectionViewOrthogonalScrollerEmbeddedScrollView`. But this scrollView is private so that access is supposed to be restricted.

If you had any ideas, please help to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem.

Use `visibleItemsInvalidationHandler`.
This method is used instead of scrollView delegate in CompositionalLayouts.

Example of the usage.

```swift
section.visibleItemsInvalidationHandler = { [weak self] visibleItems, point, environment in
    self?.pageControl.currentPage = visibleItems.last!.indexPath.row
}

return section
```